# Getting errors while building the angular application

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular8

I am getting some compilation error while building the angular project and the error is given below.

**Error:**

```
list.component.html(155,47): Property 'auth' is private and only accessible within class 'ListComponent'.
```

I am explaining my code below.

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="auth.currentUserValue.RoleName === 'admin'" (click)="editStore(element)" class="text-primary"
        style="cursor: pointer">edit</mat-icon>
    &nbsp;
    <mat-icon *ngIf="auth.currentUserValue.RoleName === 'admin'" (click)="deleteStore(element)" class="text-danger"
        style="cursor: pointer">delete_forever
    </mat-icon>
</td>
```

```js
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/_services';
constructor(private auth : AuthenticationService) {}
```

I need to clear this error.

Answer (score 1):

The `AuthenticationService` is marked as `private`. This means that it cannot be accessed outside of its containing class. Which is the component and not the template.

**Solution 1**

Mark the `AuthenticationService` as public.

```js
constructor(public auth : AuthenticationService) {}
```

This will allow your `template` to have access to it.

**Solution 2**

It's advised against to access your services or properties on your services directly from the template. Create a reference on the component instead.

```js
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/_services';

@Component({})
export class MyComponent {
  currentUserRoleName = this.auth.currentUserValue.RoleName;
  constructor(private auth : AuthenticationService) {}
}
```

Your template:

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="currentUserRoleName === 'admin'" (click)="editStore(element)" class="text-primary"
        style="cursor: pointer">
        edit</mat-icon>
    &nbsp;
    <mat-icon *ngIf="currentUserRoleName === 'admin'" (click)="deleteStore(element)" class="text-danger"
        style="cursor: pointer">delete_forever
    </mat-icon>
</td>
```